# NullPointerException parsing with JSoup

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, jsoup

With the following code,

```
Document doc = null;
doc = Jsoup.parse(page):

String myexample = "My example";

Elements myexamples = doc.select("div.yourOptions p");
   if (myexamples != null && myexamples.first().ownText() != null) myexample = myexamples.first().ownText();
```

everything seems to be good for 99.9% of my application's users.

But I received a few StackTraces with a NullPointerException at (the equivalent of) line 7. StackTrace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tomtom.joe.mobile.Suivi$BackgroundAsyncTask.doInBackground(Suivi.java:369)
at com.tomtom.joe.mobile.Suivi$BackgroundAsyncTask.doInBackground(Suivi.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 4 more
```

How could I be protected against NullPointerException ?
The content of "myexamples.first().ownText()" varies with users ! But I guess "myexamples.first().ownText()" could be null...

Example :

```
<div class="yourOptions"><div class="cockpitContent resizeHeight1">
<h2 class="Title">Title</h2>
<p>Options</p>
<p>Options 2</p>
</div></div>
```

Comment: and stacktrace ? where does the NPE happens ? (and with what content ?)

Comment: seems like `myexamples.first()` could be null

Comment: whats on the line Suivi.java:369 ?

Comment: line 369 corresponds to line 7 : if (myexamples != null && myexamples.first().ownText() != null) myexample = myexamples.first().ownText();

Comment: @njzk2 Is there a way to be protected against NullPointerException?

Comment: can post the html you r trying to parse ?

Comment: The only value you don't check for null is the value returned by first(). So that's probably the best place to start.

Comment: have u tried `.text()` instead of `.ownText()` ?

Comment: @ChrisCooney Good idea, if (myexamples.first() != null) should avoid NullPointerException ! Right?

Comment: @Shoshi The problem is that I can't reproduce the problem myself. I have to bet to try to avoid NullPointerException.

Comment: I'll post the answer, then if you are convinced it has worked, you can mark it as correct for future readers. :)

Comment: do u want to get all the `<p>`s text value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myexamples.first()` is the only value here that isn't checked for a `null` value. This suggests the source of your error is this value.

Comment: I'll let you know as soon as I get the answer.

Comment: Indeed myexamples.first() can be null

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div.cockpitContent > p");
for(Element element : elements){
    if(element != null && element.text() != null){
        String value = element.text();
        // do your job
    }
}
```

N.B: i haven't test this code. you should try this.